# How to make images responsive using CSSGrid

Tags: html, css

Im trying to insert 8 images into a 2x4 CSSGrid. I have width set to 100% but when I set height to 100% the bottom row of images end up below the footer instead of below the first row of images. Setting the height using px works, but its not responsive at all compared to using %. Any ideas? Ive been told using flexbox would be better but I want to just strictly use CSSGrid for this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout Master</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="zone green">
            <span>About</span>
            <span>Products</span>
            <span>Our Team</span>
            <span id="Contact">Contact</span>
      </div>
      <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
      <div class="zone blue">
        <img src="data_storage_2_2.png" alt="data storage">
        <img src="desktop_analytics_2.png" alt="desktop analytics">
        <img src="files_2.png" alt="files">
        <img src="monitor_coding_2.png" alt="monitor coding">
        <img src="monitor_settings_2.png" alt="monitor settings">
        <img src= "server_2_2.png" alt="server">
        <img src="server_3.png" alt="server">
        <img src="server_safe_2.png" alt=server safe>
      </div>
      <div class="zone yellow">Made By Cristobal Manrique</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 8fr 1fr;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.green span{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#Contact {
  margin-left: auto; 
}

.zone.blue{

    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));

}
.zone {
    padding:30px 50px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{

    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{

    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}

img{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@msmoore's anser can be used, but that then restricts your height.

Instead I've provided a jsFiddle of your example with some sample images from imgur [check it out here.](https://jsfiddle.net/byp06zne/)

The real change was adding `object-fit: cover;` to your `img` css like this.

```
img {
    object-fit: cover; /* ensures the image tries to cover all the space given to it */
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Still this is not ideal code when dealing with images/galleries - try to use bootstrap or some similar library that offers more responsive grid solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 100vh instead of 100%

Comment: I used 30vh, instead of 100 because while it wasn't putting the images in the wrong area, it was making the images really long, probably an issue with the image aspect ratio maybe? But, thanks for your answer, it really helped. It seems responsive now on chrome, but do you know if its responsive across devices too?

Comment: If you go into the console and click on the icon that looks like a tablet next to the arrow you can have a look at how it looks on different devices. Tablets, phones etc. Is that what you mean? Or did you mean cross-browser compatible? If so view height (vh) is supported across 94% of browsers so you should be good on using vh if it indeed works as you want

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to wrap your images with a container:

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="data_storage_2_2.png" alt="data storage">
</div>
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/qeqajozoge/edit?html,css,output

`height: 100%` only works when the ancestor element also has a defined height. If the parent's height is not defined, the browser will look at the parent's parent height until it finds a defined height (and so on) to resolve it. You do not want the parent's height, but the height of the grid row and the result is unexpected. A workaround is to add a container div which adjusts itself to the grid, and you can set your image's height to 100%.

Note that setting the images' heights will distort them, it is better if you can keep their aspect ratio. In such case you can consider other solutions like @Danail Gabenski's answer. The vh solution however will not give you the result you want in this case.